# I have seen these in when trying to build a cross compiler what does these mean

Tags: command-line, kernel, gcc

```
../gcc-x.y.z/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers


export PREFIX="$HOME/opt/cross"


export TARGET=i586-elf


export PATH="$PREFIX/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export PREFIX="$HOME/opt/cross"
```

The assigned path for HOME variable are added before /opt/cross and the whole path was assigned to variable PREFIX.

```
export PATH="$PREFIX/bin:$PATH"
```

Then the assigned path for PREFIX variable are added befor /bin and the whole path was exported to Environmental path.

```
export TARGET=i586-elf
```

i586-elf was assigned to TARGET variable.